# Authentication logic doesn't work on Azure hosted ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Please bear with me as I'm a noob in Azure technology. I have one ASP.NET MVC application hosted on Azure where forms authentication has been implemented. The application works fine locally. But on Azure hosted website the session object in `AuthorizationContext` becomes null. The `if` condition mentioned below in the custom authorize attribute always turns out to be true.

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated && filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserInfo"] == null)
        {
              -------  Redirect to login page -----------------------
        }

        -----------------------------------------------
    }
```

Also `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` is always false.

After searching a lot on internet I have not been able to find any clue about why this is happening. Is there any setting I'm missing in Azure configuration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many instances of the service are you running? What session provider are you using, `InProc`? If you are running more than 1 instance with `InProc` session, the information is probably being lost as your session is being bounced across instances.

Comment: @ danludwig : Only 1 instance is running